# jQuery: how can i pass parameters to event listeners' callback?

Tags: callback, jquery

```
function myClass(myobject){
      var myclass = {};

      myclass.registerEvent = function(){
          $('#'+myobject.id).live('someEventThatTriggersRightAway', runMe);
      };

      runMe = function(){
            $('#'+myobject.id).die('someEventThatTriggersRightAway', runMe);
            console.log("Hello "+myobject.name);
      };

      return myclass;
}


var instance1 = new myClass({id:'button1',name:'MATO'});
var instance2 = new myClass({id:'button2',name:'YAMA'});
```

when i run this code

```
instance1.registerEvent();
```

the result is

```
Hello YAMA
```

it is as if the first instance had been overwritten by the 2nd one. I can solve this if only i can pass the 'myobject' in the event's callback, but i dont know how to do it. and also i cant kill it if it has parameters. how can i do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the `var` from `runMe`, so `runMe` is leaking to the global execution context. Therefore, each time you call `myClass`, the reference to `myobject` in `runMe` is going to change.

```
var runMe = function(){
    $('#'+myobject.id).die('someEventThatTriggersRightAway', runMe);
    console.log("Hello "+myobject.name);
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SAEP7/).

---

Side note: are you aware that the jQuery `.live()` and `.die()` methods are deprecated? You should be using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: wow i love you man! i felt so stupid. i didnt knew you should put var on functions too! wow! this basically solved my problems. i have a question... i used bind() and unbind() and its working... is that ok? or delegate() should be better?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) You can use `bind` and `unbind` if the elements exist in the DOM at the time the code runs. You can use `delegate` to delegate the event higher up the DOM tree if not.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is purely theoretical, since `.live()` and `.die()` are deprecated, and therefore *should not be used anymore*. To get your code up to date, substitue the `.live()`/`.die()` calls given below with the following:

```
// for .live()
$(document).on('click', '#'+myobject.id, myobject, runMe);

// for .die()
$(document).off('click', '#'+e.data.id, runMe);
```

Here, you can and should replace `document` with the nearest static parent element of the buttons. [**New code demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/damz7/1/)

---

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/), data is an optional second parameter to the `.live()` method, which you access through the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/). Use as follows:

```
function myClass(myobject){
      var myclass = {};

      myclass.registerEvent = function(){
          $('#'+myobject.id).live('click', myobject, runMe);
      };

      var runMe = function(e){
          $('#'+e.data.id).die('click', runMe);
          console.log("Hello "+e.data.name);
      };

      return myclass;
}

var instance1 = new myClass({id:'button1',name:'MATO'});
var instance2 = new myClass({id:'button2',name:'YAMA'});

instance1.registerEvent();
instance2.registerEvent();
```

[**Old code working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/damz7/)

Comment: wow man! thanks! i didnt knew that the live and die is now deprecated. i tried bind and unbind is that ok? anyway, i tried your working demo and its working great! thanks really!